# Extending Validation Class fuelphp?

Tags: php, validation, fuelphp

Fuelphp Extending Validation classes link
http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/validation/validation.html#rules

Hi guys

I am facing a very critical problem for Extending Validation classes.
Can anyone suggest a solution to me, and how the step is done, as well as how can perform it ????

This is the way I done it

[Screenshot of Image 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0fam6vt68y6a07/Screenshots.7z)

I try to add class at path(fuel/app/myrules) with below class

```
<?php
class MyRules
{
    // note this is a non-static method
    public function _validation_is_upper($val)
    {
    return $val === strtoupper($val);
    }

}
?>
```

Image 2

Next at the controller, adding this for call

```
  $val = Validation::forge();
  $val->add_model('_validation_is_upper');
```

but nothing happens.

The fuelphp document is incomplete.

Comment: The image link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0fam6vt68y6a07/Screenshots.7z

Comment: My project folder  
https://copy.com/9PBKImlY36rTkj08

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = Validation::forge();
$val->add_callable(new MyRules());
```

Comment: Finally i find the solution. IS

  $val = Validation::forge();
  $val->add_callable('myrules');
  $val->add('[member_name]', 'testing')->add_rule('is_upperxxxxx');

Comment: But still not effective to using it, you got any more suggestion